# Knockout set observable array in array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a small question about knockout.

I have made a viewmodel 
that looks like this (there are more subitems then Actions)

```
{
"PlatformSettings": [
    {
        "Actions": [
            {
                "Selected": false,
                "Text": "None",
                "Value": "None"
            },
            {
                "Selected": true,
                "Text": "Validation1",
                "Value": "Validation1"
            },
            {
                "Selected": true,
                "Text": "Validation2",
                "Value": "Validation2"
            },
            {
                "Selected": true,
                "Text": "Validation3",
                "Value": "Validation3"
            }
        ],
        "Platform": {
            "Id": "89",
            "Description": "ONTWIKKELB"
        }
    },{
        "Actions": [
            {
                "Selected": false,
                "Text": "None",
                "Value": "None"
            },
            {
                "Selected": true,
                "Text": "Validation1",
                "Value": "Validation1"
            },
            {
                "Selected": true,
                "Text": "Validation2",
                "Value": "Validation2"
            },
            {
                "Selected": true,
                "Text": "Validation3",
                "Value": "Validation3"
            }
        ],
        "Platform": {
            "Id": "89",
            "Description": "ONTWIKKELB"
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but when i edit the checkboxes in my view and map them

```
 self.Save = function(validate) {
        var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);            
        ******
        return false;
};
```

unmapped doesn't show the changes. And all the select values still show as on page load. I tried to make observable arrays, but the past 2 hours, but i can't figure it out.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Making the array observable will notify subscribers on add\remove. Making the "selected" property of each element observable will notify subscribers when it changes and allow 2 way binding.

So basically, make the selected property of each array element an observable too.

Comment: ALSO: The http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/ plugin allows this to be done dynamically to wrap\unwrap any POJO in observables dynamically.